# Find missing dates in multiple date ranges for multi groups

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to extract missing date list for a date range in columns `DATE FROM` and `DATE TO` for multiple groups in column `CURRENCY`, the ranges is splited in multiple rows for each group column `CURRENCY` :

For example : Currency EUR have three date ranges in row 0, 1 and 2, and the missing range in the entire group is 2021-10-06 to 2021-10-10.

Missing ranges is highlited below using `*` symbol, This missing date range is what i desire in expected output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CURRENCY":{"0":"EUR","1":"EUR","2":"EUR","3":"GBP","4":"GBP","5":"GBP","6":"USD","7":"USD","8":"SAR","9":"SAR"},
                   "DATE FROM":{"0":"2021-10-01","1":"2021-10-11","2":"2021-10-19","3":"2021-10-01","4":"2021-10-05",
                                "5":"2021-10-11","6":"2021-10-01","7":"2021-10-05","8":"2021-10-01","9":"2021-10-05"},
                   "DATE TO":{"0":"2021-10-05","1":"2021-10-18","2":"2021-10-23","3":"2021-10-04","4":"2021-10-07",
                              "5":"2021-10-18","6":"2021-10-02","7":"2021-10-10","8":"2021-10-01","9":"2021-10-10"}})

    CURRENCY    DATE FROM   DATE TO
0   EUR         2021-10-01  2021-10-05*
1   EUR         2021-10-11* 2021-10-18
2   EUR         2021-10-19  2021-10-23
3   GBP         2021-10-01  2021-10-04
4   GBP         2021-10-05  2021-10-07*
5   GBP         2021-10-11* 2021-10-18
6   USD         2021-10-01  2021-10-02*
7   USD         2021-10-05* 2021-10-10
8   SAR         2021-10-01  2021-10-01*
9   SAR         2021-10-05* 2021-10-10
```

Expected output:

```
    CURRENCY    MISSING
0   EUR         2021-10-06
1   EUR         2021-10-07
2   EUR         2021-10-08
3   EUR         2021-10-09
4   EUR         2021-10-10
5   GBP         2021-10-08
6   GBP         2021-10-09
7   GBP         2021-10-10
8   USD         2021-10-03
9   USD         2021-10-04
10  SAR         2021-10-02
11  SAR         2021-10-03
12  SAR         2021-10-04
```

Below is what i have tried, but it seems this is not efficient way to resolve, also im not sure how to group those output ranges to find the missing dates for each group (EUR,GBP...etc) :

```
date_from_list = df['DATE FROM'].to_list()
date_to_list = df['DATE TO'].to_list()
curr_list = df['CURRENCY'].to_list()

for date_from, date_to, curr in zip(date_from_list, date_to_list, curr_list):
    print(curr_list, pd.date_range(date_from, date_to))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to solve your problem, which is comparing lists of the total ranges for each currency with list of the individual ranges of each row. The filtering with the nested loops can likely be optimized.

```py
import numpy as np
df['dateranges'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['DATE FROM'],x['DATE TO']), axis=1)
total_ranges = (df.groupby("CURRENCY")
                .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['DATE FROM'].min(),x['DATE TO'].max())))
individual_ranges = df.groupby("CURRENCY")['dateranges'].apply(list).apply(np.concatenate)

currency = []
missing = []
for curr in total_ranges.index:
    for date in total_ranges[curr]:
        if date not in individual_ranges[curr]:
            currency.append(curr)
            missing.append(date)

result = pd.DataFrame({'CURRENCY': currency,
                       'MISSING':missing})
```

Answer (score 2):

Both pd.date_range and pd.period_range can do. I have used date range which only has close either right or left, so you may have to do some filter. Code below

```
df= df.assign(end=df['DATE FROM'].shift(-1),start=df['DATE TO']).iloc[:-1 , :]#Define the start and end for date range

df=df.assign(Missing=df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['start'],  end=x['end'], closed='right').tolist(), axis = 1)).explode('Missing').drop_duplicates('Missing').drop(['start','end'],axis=1)

  CURRENCY   DATE FROM     DATE TO    Missing
0      EUR  2021-10-01  2021-10-05 2021-10-06
0      EUR  2021-10-01  2021-10-05 2021-10-07
0      EUR  2021-10-01  2021-10-05 2021-10-08
0      EUR  2021-10-01  2021-10-05 2021-10-09
0      EUR  2021-10-01  2021-10-05 2021-10-10
0      EUR  2021-10-01  2021-10-05 2021-10-11
1      EUR  2021-10-11  2021-10-18 2021-10-19
2      EUR  2021-10-19  2021-10-23        NaT
3      GBP  2021-10-01  2021-10-04 2021-10-05
6      USD  2021-10-01  2021-10-02 2021-10-03
6      USD  2021-10-01  2021-10-02 2021-10-04
8      SAR  2021-10-01  2021-10-01 2021-10-02
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses a package called [`piso`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), (pandas interval set operations) and will be fast.

**setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CURRENCY":{"0":"EUR","1":"EUR","2":"EUR","3":"GBP","4":"GBP","5":"GBP","6":"USD","7":"USD","8":"SAR","9":"SAR"},
               "DATE FROM":{"0":"2021-10-01","1":"2021-10-11","2":"2021-10-19","3":"2021-10-01","4":"2021-10-05",
                            "5":"2021-10-11","6":"2021-10-01","7":"2021-10-05","8":"2021-10-01","9":"2021-10-05"},
               "DATE TO":{"0":"2021-10-05","1":"2021-10-18","2":"2021-10-23","3":"2021-10-04","4":"2021-10-07",
                          "5":"2021-10-18","6":"2021-10-02","7":"2021-10-10","8":"2021-10-01","9":"2021-10-10"}})

df["DATE FROM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE FROM"])
df["DATE TO"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE TO"]) + pd.Timedelta("1d")
```

Note I am changing data to be `pandas.Timestamp` and adding a day to the end dates.  This is because you seem to be interpreting dates as periods, i.e. an entire day, where we will be working with instants in time.

**solution**

Groupby currency and create an interval index for each currency

```
interval_arrays = df.groupby("CURRENCY").apply(lambda d: pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(d["DATE FROM"], d["DATE TO"]))
```

`interval_arrays` looks like this

```
CURRENCY
EUR    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-01, 2021-10-06], (2021...
GBP    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-01, 2021-10-05], (2021...
SAR    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-01, 2021-10-02], (2021...
USD    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-01, 2021-10-03], (2021...
dtype: object
```

Create the missing intervals, as `pandas.IntervalIndex` using `piso.complement`.

```
import piso
missing = interval_arrays.apply(piso.complement)
```

`missing` looks like

```
CURRENCY
EUR    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-06, 2021-10-11]], ...
GBP    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-08, 2021-10-11]], ... 
SAR    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-02, 2021-10-05]], ...
USD    IntervalIndex([(2021-10-03, 2021-10-05]], ...
dtype: object
```

Next we need to convert the intervals in each `IntervalIndex` into date ranges and combine the date ranges into a single `pandas.DatetimeIndex` which gets wrapped up in a dataframe

```
def calc(currency, interval_index):
    date_ranges = [pd.date_range(i.left, i.right, closed="left") for i in interval_index]
    combined = date_ranges[0].union_many(date_ranges[1:])
    return pd.DataFrame({"MISSING":combined}).assign(CURRENCY=currency)

pd.concat([calc(currency, interval_index) for currency, interval_index in missing.iteritems() if len(interval_index) > 0])
```

The result is the following dataframe

```
    MISSING CURRENCY
0 2021-10-06      EUR
1 2021-10-07      EUR
2 2021-10-08      EUR
3 2021-10-09      EUR
4 2021-10-10      EUR
0 2021-10-08      GBP
1 2021-10-09      GBP
2 2021-10-10      GBP
0 2021-10-02      SAR
1 2021-10-03      SAR
2 2021-10-04      SAR
0 2021-10-03      USD
1 2021-10-04      USD
```

Comment: Thnaks for the answer!, but i get (IndexError: list index out of range) error.

Comment: Can you confirm that you used the same setup code?  It runs without error on my machine.

Comment: Are you running it on data where for a particular currency there is no gaps? That might be where an error is coming from. I've made an edit to the `pd.concat` line to fix this case.

Comment: Ill try updated script withy data, thanks!